# Compress dict sum statement with Python

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda

In my python application I have a big list (now with almost 9000 indexes). I need to find the two most similar items in this list. So, what I have now is something like:

```
aux1 = 0
aux2 = 1
min_distance = 0xffff

weights = get_weights()

for i in range(0, len(_list)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(_list)):

        obj1 = _list[i]
        obj2 = _list[j]
        dist = 0

        for key in self.__fields:
            dist += weights[key] * (obj1[key] - obj2[key]) ** 2

        if dist < min_distance:
            min_distance = dist
            aux1 = i
            aux2 = j

return aux1, aux2, min_distance
```

In the code, `weights` is a dict, `obj1` and `obj2` are both objects in which the `__getitem__` is implemented and the return value also comes from  a dict. And `self.__fields` is a list with the selected fields (it has now 9 items).

My problem is, this loop is taking too much time to complete. Even after 5 hours, the `i` variable still in the first 100th list items.

With this next silly code, I come to the conclusion that the problem is not the size of the list (the silly code finishes with 5 minutes of difference).

```
count = 0
total = 9000

for i in range(0, total):
    for j in range(i + 1, total):
        for k in range(0, 10):
            count += 1

print("Count is " + str(count))
```

Therefore, the problem seems to be in the most internal loop of my code:

```
            for key in self.__fields:
                dist += weights[key] * (obj1[key] - obj2[key]) ** 2
```

I know Python, but I'm not a Python specialist. I conclude that the access to the values of three objects through their key is a slow operation. Some time ago, I saw in some blog that list comprehensions and/or lambda operations can be faster.

So, my question is: how do I make this most internal loop faster using list comprehensions and/or lambda? Feel free to give any other advice if you want.

Comment: First change your `range` to `xrange`.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm using Python3 and it seems that `xrange` is only for Python2, right?

Comment: Ok, then it's fine. `range` in python 3 is same as `xrange` of python2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether it's any faster, but you could rewrite that code using `itertools.combinations` and get the `min` using a `key` function calculating the "distance".

```
from itertools import combinations
weights = get_weights()
aux1, aux2 = min(combinations(_list, 2), 
                 key=lambda pair: sum(weights[key] * (pair[0][key] - pair[1][key]) ** 2 
                                      for key in self.__fields))
```

If this does not help, you might consider temporarily turning the dictionaries in `_list` into lists, holding just the values of the relevant fields. Instead of using dictionary lookup, you can then just `zip` those lists together with the weights. Afterwards, turm them back into dicts.

```
weights_list = [weights[f] for f in self.__fields]
as_lists = [[d[f] for f in self.__fields] for d in _list]
aux1, aux2 = min(combinations(as_lists, 2), 
                 key=lambda pair: sum(w * (x - y) ** 2 
                                      for w, x, y in zip(weights_list, *pair)))

aux1, aux2 = (dict(zip(self.__fields, x)) for x in (aux1, aux2))
```

This should be a bit faster, but it will only work if the dicts do not have any other fields than those in `self.__fields`, otherwise the dicts can not be reconstructed from the lists (at least not as easily). Alternatively, you might use tuples instead of lists and use another dictionary to map those tuples to the original dictionaries...

Or try this, using the indices of the elements instead of the elements themselves (not tested):

```
idx1, idx2 = min(combinations(range(len(_list)), 2), 
                 key=lambda pair: sum(w * (x - y) ** 2 
                                      for w, x, y in zip(weights_list, as_list[pair[0]], as_list[pair[1]])))
aux1, aux2 = _lists[idx1], _lists[idx2]
```

Comment: I tried to understand your code, but I haven't used combinations yet. Looking at the documentation, it seems to expect also a second parameter, which is the length of the subsequence. What would be the second parameter? And how is `t` related to the list?

Comment: @Rick Whoops, I totally forgot the second parameter. Thank for pointing out, should be fixed now. About `t`: That's one of the tuples generated by `combinations`, corresponding to `(obj1, obj2)` in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your code. I tested your first approach and it takes more or less the same time as the "normal" approach (I didn't have the time to make a benchmark, but your first approach takes ~14 min, same as the "normal one"). I'm going to try your second suggestion. Thanks! :)

Comment: As for the second approach, much faster (~ 3 min)! Thanks! The only problem now that seems to happen, is that when the objects are recreated (`aux1, aux2 = (dict(zip(self.__fields, x)) for x in (aux1, aux2))`), they are not the same from the previous ones. I mean, they have the same values of course, but they are different objects. Would be there a way to get the indexes of those objects, instead of their clones?

Comment: Really nice! Even with your "not tested" notes, your code works very fine. Everything seems to be working now! I'm looking forward to the results of this. Thanks again! Your answer was really helpful! Last question (this is not important at all, but would be nice to have): is there a way to also get the min result from the lambda function?

Comment: @Rick I think it would be easiest to apply the `lambda` again to the result of `min` afterwards.

Comment: True. If I have the minimum indexes already, it's just calculate the lambda for only these indexes again. Thanks!